# Diablo 2 digital download patch level

Tags: diablo-ii

I am trying to play Diablo 2 with my flat mate over LAN but it looks as if my CD has seen some better days (and some sand paper).  Suffice to say I cannot play.  I am trying to stay with v1.00 as apparently later patches make the single player too hard to play through multiple times.  Does anyone know if the digital download from Blizzard is v1.00 and whether it stays as v1.00 or does it auto update like Starcraft or WoW?

Comment: What do you mean "make the single player too hard to play through multiple times"?  I frequently played Diablo 2 single player, and I don't remember any problems with the later patches.

Comment: well i have been informed, not having played through multiple times, that later patches granted mobs an immunity to certain damage types that could make it, if not impossible, ridiculously hard for someone on their own.  may not be true but as i said have not gone that far through diablo 2 myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no say in the matter; for the digital download they give you a Blizzard downloader and that gives you the game in a patched state.

Looking at my downloaded installers from when I did it last (Nov 2010), I have 1.12A for D2 and LOD, then I had to manually patch to 1.13 (released Mar 2010) to play on Battle.Net.  Apparently they don't keep it totally up-to-date, nor is it automatically updated, but you also can't get 1.0 either.

That said, my friends and I did 1.13 on ladder without much trouble at least up to the end of Nightmare without any difficulty issues.

Comment: thanks for the heads up with the digital downloader.  it is what i expected so glad i did not take the plunge.  may track down a set of disks on amazon.  Ta